# Error when editing JSON data in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I am new to Node.js and server-side scripting. I am currently creating a login page with Node.js as server side lang. I have stored some user details in JSON data by default.

I want to read the JSON file for authentication and also edit it for new user entries; so I am basically looking for ways to do it. Here is a sample of the JSON file:

```
{
    "table-name" : "user-details",
    {
        //user1 - details
    },
    {
        //user2 - details
    } 
}
```

I am using Intellij as IDE with NodeJS plugin installed. So I tried to use file system to access JSON file but I got different error, common one was:

> Can't set headers after they are sent

This is the code I tried:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var fs  = require('fs');

/* GET login page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
   res.render('login', { title: 'something' });

   // Asynchronous read
   fs.readFile('user.json', function (err, data) {
      if (err) {
         return console.error(err);
      }
      console.log("Asynchronous read: " + data.toString());
   });
});
```

Are there any ways to do this? And why did i get this error? I searched for a while in Google but couldn't solve it. A detailed answer will be welcomed.

Comment: Do you get inside of the error if?

Comment: yeah, i got a error message

Comment: try putting the res.render after the readFile

Comment: if i add res.render after readfile, i get error message "fd must be a file descriptor".

Comment: Just as a test, can you remove the `return` from `return console.error(err);` so you just have `console.error(err);` and tell me what happens?

Comment: Do you want to use the data from the JSON for the login or why are you reading it after you have rendered the page?

Comment: yeah i wan to use the data from  json for login

Answer (score 0):

The error **"Error: Can't set headers after they are sent."** means that your response is already in the Body or Finished, but some function is trying to set a header or a statusCode, and that is not allowed.

In this case you call the res.render(). This causes that your response is Finished. After that, you try to read the file and your code throws an error. Since you are still in the handler **function(req, res, next)**, Express is able to capture your error and tries to send a statusCode **500**, but since your response is already finished, you get the **"Can't set headers after they are sent"** error.

What I mean is the reason you get the **headers error** has nothing to do with headers, it is all about fs module and the readFile call. So try to fix the readFile error, and you will fix the headers error at the same time.

Hope it helps

PD: I assume your JSON file is just for testing purposes, but if your planning to parse that JSON after you read with fs, I think this is not a valid JSON. Perhaps you could create a key "users" and store all the information within an Array.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to NodeJS!

You'll find great packages to help with user authentication and session (data) management I'm sure, such as Passport (https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport).

To answer your question a response (res) sends data to the front-end so you want to do that last not first.

```
router.get('/', function(req, res) {

  // Asynchronous read
  fs.readFile('user.json', function (err, data) {

    var logMessage = err ? err : "Asynchronous read: " + data.toString();

    res.render('login', { title: 'something' });

  });

});
```